# Kotlin how to get uri after camera intent

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, camera

I'm making a mobile application in Kotlin that allows you to search for photos in the gallery. I managed to get an image from the gallery, get its URI, and save it in a folder in my app. But now I would also like to implement the ability to take the photo directly from the application. My problem is that once the camera is opened and the photo is taken, I have nothing to save in the application folder.

I looked on the web but there is no tutorial for this.

There is my Activity:

```
class AddMemorieActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 1
    private val PICK_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA = 2

    // Pour récuperer le path de l'image ajoutée
    private var imagePath: String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_memorie)


        // Demande de permission à la camera


        //PHOTO
        val bouton_ajout_image =  findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ajouter_image)

        bouton_ajout_image.setOnClickListener{
            showImagePickerDialog()
        }


        // Récuperation de la liste des émotions pour le radio

        val rem : RequestEmotions = RequestEmotions(applicationContext)
        val emotions = rem.getEmotions({response -> create_emotion_radio(response)})


        
    //-------------------------------
    // GESTION DE L'IMPORTATION DE L'IMAGE
    //-------------------------------

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val imageUri: Uri? = data?.extras?.get("data") as Uri

            if (imageUri != null) {
                val directory = File(filesDir, "images")
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs()
                }

                val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
                val fileName = "IMG_$timestamp.jpg"
                val file = File(directory, fileName)

                try {
                    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

                    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (true) {
                        bytesRead = inputStream?.read(buffer) ?: -1
                        if (bytesRead == -1) {
                            break
                        }
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }

                    inputStream?.close()
                    outputStream.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                imagePath = file.absolutePath

                val bouton_ajout_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ajouter_image)
                bouton_ajout_image.setOnClickListener {
                    showImagePickerDialog()
                }

                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imagePath)
                    .into(bouton_ajout_image)
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            if (data != null ) {
                val imageUri: Uri = ??????
                println("=====================")
                println(imageUri)
                val directory = File(filesDir, "images")
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs()
                }

                val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
                val fileName = "IMG_$timestamp.jpg"
                val file = File(directory, fileName)

                try {
                    val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

                    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (true) {
                        bytesRead = inputStream?.read(buffer) ?: -1
                        if (bytesRead == -1) {
                            break
                        }
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }

                    inputStream?.close()
                    outputStream.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                imagePath = file.absolutePath

                val bouton_ajout_image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ajouter_image)
                bouton_ajout_image.setOnClickListener {
                    showImagePickerDialog()
                }

                Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imagePath)
                    .into(bouton_ajout_image)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY)
    }

    
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Gestion choix caméra
    //----------------------------------------------------------------


    // Dialog pour demander de choisir ou récupérer la photo
    private fun showImagePickerDialog() {
        // Création du tableau des options
        val options = arrayOf("Galerie", "Appareil photo")
        // Création de la boîte de dialogue
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Choisir une image depuis:")
        builder.setItems(options) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> pickImageFromGallery()
                1 -> captureImageFromCamera()
            }
        }
        // Affichage de la boîte de dialogue
        builder.show()
    }

    // Gestion du choix d'ouvrir la caméra
    private fun captureImageFromCamera() {
        val perm = checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        if (perm) {
            try {
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_FROM_CAMERA)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "L'application de l'appareil photo n'est pas disponible.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'ouverture de l'appareil photo.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun checkPermission(permission: String): Boolean {
        var res = true
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(permission), 0)
            }
            res = false
        }
        return res
    }


}
```

I tried some Java code that I translate, but i still have errors.

Comment: `once the camera is opened and the photo is taken, I have nothing to save in the application folder.` You do not have to save anything as the used Camera app will save the image using the uri you provided in the intent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the uri from intent(data)

```
 val imageUri: Uri = ?????? ->  val imageUri: Uri = data.data
```

Comment: I tried but I have a NullPointerException

Comment: is it possible to log data.data value and data.extras value ? @Ameliorer

Comment: data.data = null and data.extras = Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=78556]

data.extras.get("data") = android.graphics.Bitmap@3e4ff1e

Comment: It's very strange that the image was put directly in extras, because there are limitations for bundle size up to 1 MB. But as we can see from logs you should get bimap from data.extras.get("data")

Answer (score 0):

> val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

So you first have a File object indicating where the image should be written.

Then you use FileProvider to get a nice uri for that File.

And finally you use an intent.putExtra() to send the uri to the Camera app.

Further you will use that File object in onActivityResult.

Comment: Can you give me an example please ? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#kotlin

Comment: `I looked on the web but there is no tutorial for this.`